# When clicked on a checkbox, JS should populate an input field. But it's not, what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a list of items that are input fields in a form.
I'm trying to change the value of an input field if the user clicks on a checkbox.

### Here's my HTML:

First item:

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="pago[405][498.35]" id="pago[405][498.35]" value="498.35" data-idUF=405> A pagar $ 498.35</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="monto[405]" name="monto[405]" placeholder="0" readonly>
```

Second item:

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="pago[406][254.23]" id="pago[406][254.23]" value="254.23" data-idUF=406> A pagar $ 254.23</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="monto[406]" name="monto[406]" placeholder="0" readonly>
```

Third item:

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="pago[407][328.22]" id="pago[407][328.22]" value="328.22" data-idUF=407> A pagar $ 328.22</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="monto[407]" name="monto[407]" placeholder="0" readonly>
```

And so on...

### Now, I want the checkbox of the first item, when clicked, to add the value of that checkbox into the input field:

```
const pago = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=pago]');
const monto = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=monto]');


  for (let i = 0; i < pago.length; i++) {
    const uid = pago[i].dataset.iduf;
    const valor = pago[i].value;

    pago[i].addEventListener('change', function(){
      if (this.checked) { 
      monto[i].value = valor;
      } else {
        monto[i].value = '';
      }
  });
  }
```

### It should look like this:

[image]

[image]

But it doesn't, and the console does not show any error.
If I try to replace `monto[i].value = valor;` for `monto[uid].value = valor;`, it tells me that `monto[i]` is `undefined`.

Comment: in `data-idUF=405` attribute inside the input, you need to do `"405"` as a string I think to work (this is the first thing that came to my mind since I see color highlighting on StackOverflow make the <input white when the second input code is colored correctly) I think is a typo (like not closing label or number attribute need to be string)

Comment: it works fine for me in jsfiddle but it seems you miss a label opening tag  here, look closely :
`<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="pago[406][254.23]" id="pago[406][254.23]" value="254.23" data-idUF=406> A pagar $ 254.23</label>`